I have a java webapp hosted in tomcat using JAX-RS that i get a 404 when trying to access endpoint
I have a webapp where I am deploying the war file to a tomcat server. I am always getting a 404. In the catalina.out, i see the deployment but get no error.
The app runs fine as an exploded war on my dev box in intellij
the war file deploys in the tomcat webapp directory as ATools
The URL I am trying to hit is http://mydomain:8080/ATools/api/atools/check
I get a 404 and no error or anything in catalina.out
I see the 404 in the localhost access log file
I have placed an index.jsp in the root of the app and if I go to http://mydomain:8080/ATools the index page is displayed
I see my classes files and lib in the webapps/Atools/WEB-INF
I have another webapp on the same tomcat server that I cloned that has a similar layout that works fine.
I must be missing some config somewhere.
any suggestions on how to debug this (generate some kind of error) or some file to look at would be greatly appreciated
My application file
package com.mydom.ai;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {


}

My resource file
package com.mydom.ai;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/atools")
public class AiResource {


   @GET
   @Path("/")
   public Response index() {
       return Response.ok("Status: OK").build();
   }

   @GET
   @Path("/check")
   public Response parseGet() {

      try{
          ACheck check = new ACheck();
          check.check();
      }catch (Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      return Response.ok().entity("Check OK").build();
  }
}

When I push the war file , this is what I see in the catalina.out
11-Dec-2024 11:31:20.615 INFO [localhost-startStop-4] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.65/webapps/Atools.war]
11-Dec-2024 11:31:22.509 INFO [localhost-startStop-4] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
11-Dec-2024 11:31:22.525 INFO [localhost-startStop-4] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.65/webapps/Atools.war] has finished in [1,910] ms

Also if I go to the manager app I see it deployed in the manager app list
Some more info
I have two webapps. One deploys and works and one does not
the one that works when it deploys i see
24/12/11 18:49:16 Version:148 - WELD-000900: 3.1.8 (Final)
24/12/11 18:49:17 Bootstrap:236 - WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
24/12/11 18:49:17 Bootstrap:235 - WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container 58776860-2afa-406e-a40e-00c03fc446bb initialized

The one that does not deploy i do not see this message. Searching it is suggested that it could be an issue with the beans.xml.
I have a beans.xml is both project in the same place
they both look like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                  
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
        bean-discovery-mode="all">
   </beans>


can you share tomcat's logs (catalina.out)? Your webapp is probably not deployed properly.

@art1go added catalina.out to description

You should state your versions, and your choice of implementation. Perhaps post your build configuration (POM, etc).

try removing the backslash on the Path and try again

no difference Malick
